# Nails holding drywall

Tags: drywall

The upstairs of my house was remodeled before I bought it. The whole house used to be plaster and lath but the upstairs is now drywall. The upstairs drywall has needed some minor repairs ever since I've moved in.

What I've noticed is that the majority of the blemishes that need to be repaired are nails. It is as though the nails are popping the joint compound off the walls and ceiling. Further, it looks like the drywall is actually held in with nails.

Is it common to attach drywall with nails?

Should I pull the nails and replace them with screws before fixing the blemishes?

Comment: This is super common because hammers are cheaper than screw guns for a crew of installers.  The blemishes even have a common term - "nail pops".

Comment: @JPhi1618 - If I ever saw a drywall crew use nails I would not only make them use screws but never think about hiring them again.   We know that no matter what nails will pop after a 10-15 years, this isn't a matter of opinion.   If drywall crew is cutting corners here who knows what else they do.

Comment: @DMoore, absolutely.  Screws are the norm now - I should have stated it was very common in the past.  I have a 90's house full of drywall nails and I hate it.

Comment: This reminds of a builder we were about to hire.   I always ask for a complete materials list.   I saw a bunch of flat head nails... thought maybe roof.   Confirmed drywall - lost the job.b

Comment: This used to be common, 30-40 years ago, before rechargeable electric screwdrivers were practical.  Had a few "nail pops" in our old house, built in 1976.  And I recall similar nail pops in the plaster of my parent's house, built ca 1955.  These were apparently caused by rust on the heads of the nails holding the "rock lath" in place.

Comment: (Don't bother pulling the nails.  If there is any rust on the nail head apply some (ta dah!) nail polish to the head.  Then drive a screw an inch or two above or below the nail before repairing the plaster.)

Comment: drwyall is supposed to be held in place by glue. The screws or nails are only to hold it unitl the glue sets

Comment: @Jasen - Not true. Most drywall is not installed with glue. Glue may be used in some specific applications but not in general.

Comment: meh, glue is considered conventional in Australia.... also makes fixing easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not common now,  it once was.

At one time it was standard practice to use nails. It could be the the structure in the wall that the nail are into is not all that solid so the heads (Pop). I always notice a few popped heads after an earthquake here.

I do not think you need to pull them, Put a screw in next to each one and then gently hammer  the nail back into place. The screw should keep the drywall from moving an thus the nail from popping out again. Then you can make your finishing repairs. Of coarse you could pull them if you want.

Comment: The renovation took place in 2008. Is that far enough back to have used nails?

Comment: Our house was built in 2002 and used nails.

Comment: I've done renovations in 2017 and used ring shank or pitch coated nails because I am a lazy bastard and nails are faster and easier to judge depth on and I'm weak and can't keep a lot of weight on the back of the drill to drive the screws in properly, sometimes. They're also easier to remove when the next renovation comes around. Screws are fine too, of course.

Comment: @vini_i  My house was flipped three years ago and they used nails... which are popping out and very noticeable now.  A few have broken through the paint...

Comment: @vini_i if the reno work was done by a handy-person then they could be using older techniques.  So yes even work done today could involve nailing drywall.

Comment: No... it's still common... probably a little more than you might think - they're just better nails (If that's what they choose to buy)..

Answer (score 9):

It was common. Now most drywall is screwed, which leads to much fewer pops.

The usual fix is to screw between the popped nails (and a few more may pop as the board is pulled tight). Then pull and patch the popped nails.

Comment: Remember, screw guns have only been widely used since the 80s and even then it was hit and miss.

Comment: @DMoore - ;-)))